# Access to answers.onstartups.com via the API?

Tags: support

Is answers.onstartups.com available via the API?

It doesn't seem to be listed in the `sites` list, but I know it is a StackExchange site.

Asking for mainly personal reasons - I want to add it to Overflow7 for my own use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably [missed it](http://stackauth.com/sites):

```
{
      "name": "OnStartups",
      "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/onstartups/img/logo.png",
      "api_endpoint": "http://api.onstartups.stackexchange.com",
      "site_url": "http://answers.onstartups.com",
      "description": "Q&A for entrepreneurs looking to start or run a new b..",
      "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/onstartups/img/apple-touch-icon.png",
      "aliases": [
        "http://onstartups.stackexchange.com",
        "http://startups.stackexchange.com"
      ],
      "state": "open_beta",
      "styling": {
        "link_color": "#0077CC",
        "tag_foreground_color": "#000",
        "tag_background_color": "#FFF"
      }
```

Comment: I looked - really I did! Sorry - just seen it there - maybe I somehow had the beta sites switched off in my app. SORRY!